# How can I make this code smoother. I am trying to draw triangle and with one touch (touches moved) i want it resize

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

How can I make this code smoother. I am trying to draw triangle and with one touch (touches moved) i want it resize. Here is my code:

```
-(id)initWithPoint:(CGPoint )point withFrame:(CGRect)frame{

    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code
        givenPoint = point;
    }
    return self;

    }

    - (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
    {
    // Drawing code

    CGContextRef ctx = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor(ctx, 0, 0, 0, 1);


    CGPoint points[6] = { CGPointMake(10, 10), CGPointMake(50, 10),
        CGPointMake(50, 10), givenPoint,
        givenPoint, CGPointMake(10, 10) };
    CGContextSetRGBFillColor(ctx, 255, 255, 255, 1);
    CGContextStrokeLineSegments(ctx, points, 6);


    }

    -(void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
    {
    UITouch *touch = [[event allTouches] anyObject];
    CGPoint location = [touch locationInView:touch.view];
    UIView *view = touch.view;

    [view removeFromSuperview];
    TailView *tailView = [[TailView alloc] initWithPoint:CGPointMake(location.x, location.y)  withFrame:CGRectMake(100, 100, location.x + 40, location.y + 40)];
    tailView.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    [self.view addSubview:tailView];

    UIPanGestureRecognizer *panRecognizer = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(move:)];
    [panRecognizer setMinimumNumberOfTouches:1];
    [panRecognizer setMaximumNumberOfTouches:1];
    [panRecognizer setDelegate:self];
    [tailView addGestureRecognizer:panRecognizer];

}
```

Comment: Are those methods part of the TailView class?

Comment: Do you want the triangle to be anchored at (10, 10) and (50, 10)?

Comment: Want to develop like this : http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/balloon-stickies-free/id414827873?mt=8
please help me.

Comment: Yes these methods are part of TailView class. My TailView should be resize and rotate as per my finger is rotate.

Answer (score 0):

In short, drawRect is slow. If you want it smooth you should use transforms. Instead of removing the view from the superview and adding it again, and hence forcing a redraw you should apply scale and rotation transform.

Comment: i want to develop same as this app.
http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/balloon-stickies-free/id414827873?mt=8